# MFC SHELLLIST does not paint

Tags: mfc, windows-shell

If I create a new MFC GUI using VS2010, create a dialog box, add an MFC SHELLLIST control to the dialog box, DoModal on the dialog box, the MFC SHELLLIST is filled with the various high level objects that can then be navigated through.

But I have an old MFC GUI that was initially created with VS2005, imported to VS2010, and when I do exactly the same as above, the MFC SHELLLIST is empty.

There are numerous MainFrm.cpp actions that are boilerplate for VS2010 that were not for VS2005. Probably one or more of them is responsible for activating MFC SHELLLIST.

Anybody know which one(s)?

Answer (score 0):

I just created a new MFC dialog application in VS2012, and added a shell list control (works fine). The biolerplate code, which is a lot less for a dialog than for an SDI/MDI application, contains the following codie in `CMyWinApp::Initinstance`

```cpp
// Create the shell manager, in case the dialog contains
// any shell tree view or shell list view controls.
CShellManager *pShellManager = new CShellManager;

// Activate "Windows Native" visual manager for enabling themes in MFC controls
CMFCVisualManager::SetDefaultManager(RUNTIME_CLASS(CMFCVisualManagerWindows));
```

The `CShellManager` is deleted when the application closes

```
// Delete the shell manager created above.
if (pShellManager != NULL)
{
    delete pShellManager;
}
```

So, I think that at least you need to create the `CShellManager` and may need the visual manager for theming.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the MFC GUI was originally developed under VS2005 then imported into VS2010. The MFC SHELLLIST would not work until I created an entirely new project with VS2010 then methodically imported the sources from the original project. Had to WinMerge sources like MainFrm.cpp and MainFrm.h in order to avoid annoying MFC SHELLLIST functionality.